# Selenium WebDriver and DropDown Boxes

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

If I want to select an option of a dropdown box, there are several ways to do that. I always used:

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("selection")).sendKeys("Germany");
```

But that didn't work every time. Sometimes another option was selected. So I googled a little bit and found this piece of code which works every time:

```java
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("selection"));
    List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for (WebElement option : options) {
        if("Germany".equals(option.getText()))
            option.click();
    }
```

But that works really really slow. If I have a long list with many items in it, it really takes too much time. So my question is, is there a solution which works every time and is fast?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could try this:

```
IWebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.Id("selection"));
SelectElement clickThis = new SelectElement(dropDownListBox);
clickThis.SelectByText("Germany");
```

Comment: I think this is some C# code or something? But it helped me to figure out the following code:
WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.id("selection"));
  Select clickThis = new Select(dropDownListBox);
  clickThis.selectByValue("Germany");

A lot faster! Thanks!

Comment: Which package should be imported for IWebElement and SelectElement?

Comment: Where can I find the SelectElement class?

Comment: Note in C# `SelectElement` is part of a different NuGet project called Selenium.Support.

Answer (score 25):

Try the following:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.Id("selection")));   
droplist.selectByVisibleText("Germany");
```

Comment: What's the scala implementation of it? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try the Select helper class and see if that makes any difference?

```
String valueToSelect= "Germany";
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("selection"));
Select dropDown = new Select(select);           
String selected = dropDown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
if(selected.equals(valueToSelect)) {//do stuff already selected}
List<WebElement> Options = dropDown.getOptions();
for(WebElement option:Options){
  if(option.getText().equals(valueToSelect)){
       option.click();  
  }
}
```

Comment: sry, this is as slow as my solution.

Answer (score 2):

For some strange reason the `SelectElement` for webdriver (version 2.25.1.0) does not properly work with the firefoxdriver (Firefox 15). Sometimes it may not select an option from a dropdownlist. It does, however, seem to work with the chromedriver... [This](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/detail?name=chromedriver_win_23.0.1240.0.zip&can=2&q=) is a link to the chromedriver... just drop it in the bin dir.

Answer (score 1):

Example for select an option from the drop down list:

Click on drop down list by using id or csspath or xpath or name. I have used id here.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownlistone")).click(); // To click on drop down list
driver.findElement(By.linkText("india")).click(); // To select a data from the drop down list.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your WebElement into Select Object as shown below

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("identifier")));
```

Once this is done you can select the required value in 3 ways. Consider an HTML file like this

```
<html>
<body>
<select id = "designation">
<option value = "MD">MD</option>
<option value = "prog"> Programmer </option>
<option value = "CEO"> CEO </option>
</option>
</select>
<body>
</html>
```

Now to identify dropdown do

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));
```

To select its option say 'Programmer' you can do

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer ");
```

or

```
 dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

or

```
 dropdown.selectByValue("prog");
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to struggle to find how to achieve especial those who are new to this tool (like me)

C# code:

```
IWebElement ddl = ffDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlGoTo")); 
OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement clickthis = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement(ddl);
clickthis.SelectByText("Your Text");
```

hope this help others!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void mulptiTransfer(WebDriver driver, By dropdownID, String text, By to)
{   
    String valuetext = null;
    WebElement element = locateElement(driver, dropdownID, 10);
    Select select = new Select(element);
    List<WebElement> options = element.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for (WebElement value: options) 
    {
        valuetext = value.getText();
        if (valuetext.equalsIgnoreCase(text))
        {
            try
            {
                select.selectByVisibleText(valuetext);
                locateElement(driver, to, 5).click();                           
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(valuetext + "Value not found in Dropdown to Select");
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select[uniq id']"));
                selectElement = new SelectElement(select);
                var optionList =
                    driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("select[uniq id']>option"));
                selectElement.SelectByText(optionList[GenerateRandomNumber(1, optionList.Count())].Text);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

```
(new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id(""))).SelectByText("");
```