# Selenium Web driver clicking images

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I select in image on and click on it using Selenium web driver? Say if it says this

```
<style type="text/css"> <ul id="nav"> <li> <li> <li> <li> <li> <a href="dashboard.action">My Dashboard</a> </li> </ul>
```

Would I use

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Dashboard")).click();
```

or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click on link in your example, you can use the selector you wrote, different kinds of css selectors (for example, `By.cssSelector("#nav a")` (looks for a link inside the "nav" list) or `By.cssSelector("a[href='dashboard.action']")` (looks for a link with specific href)) or using xPath selectors.

Comment: I'm trying to click an a text which uses css and has a ul id = "nav" and has <li>
<a href="dashboard.action">My Dashboard</a>
</li>
what code would I enter in selenium webdriver to click it

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is to have a *unique identifier* to locate your element and an identifier that *will fire 100% of the time.*

For example, if you expect the link text to change on you, then don't look for that particular link text, because you have no guarantee that it will work 100% of the time.

Similarly, if there are 30 different elements that have the same id tag, don't use that either.

If things turn out to be very complex... that is, if you are in a large page with a lot of unknown variables, find by [XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566437/java-how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium).

In the end, it really depends on the complexity of the website you are entering, and the goal of what you need done.

For more information, go to the [Selenium javadocs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) and click BY on the sidebar for a list of different methods and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to click a link with an image, it would be better to locate the element with the explicit wait.

Example :

new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));