# Select All options one by one from a listbox using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
 ***HTML***
    <select id="type" class="dropdownValues" name="type">
    <option class="dropdownValues" selected="selected" value="00">All</option>
    <option class="dropdownValues" value="01">Car</option>
    <option class="dropdownValues" value="02">House</option>
    <option class="dropdownValues" value="03">Boat</option>
    <option class="dropdownValues" value="04">Plane</option>
    <option class="dropdownValues" value="05">Tree</option>
    <option class="dropdownValues" value="06">Land</option>
    </select>
```

**My Code**

```
    Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("type")));
    List<WebElement> selectOptions = selectBox.getOptions();
    for (WebElement temp : selectOptions) 
    {


     System.out.println(temp.getText());
        }
```

***The Output is displaying 7 times.
 All
 Car
 House
 Boat
 Plane
 Tree
 Land
 All
 Car
    House
    Boat
    Plane
    Tree
    Land
    All
    Car
    House
    Boat
    Plane
    Tree
    Land
    All
    Car
    House
    Boat
    Plane
    Tree
    Land
    All
    Car
    House
    Boat
    Plane
    Tree
    Land
    All
    Car
    House
    Boat
    Plane
    Tree
    Land

```
I would like to itterate through each options 1 times  and select them.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver and DropDown Boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232544/selenium-webdriver-and-dropdown-boxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("file:///D:/Programming%20Samples/SelectOptions.html");

    WebElement item=new WebDriverWait(driver,60)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("type")));
    Select listItem=new Select(item);
    for(Integer i=0;i<listItem.getOptions().size();i++)
    {
        listItem.selectByIndex(i);
        System.out.println(listItem.getFirstSelectedOption().getText()); //Just to make sure what is selected
    }
    driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with the WebDriver in Java, but in C# you would do something like this:

```
foreach (var elem in selectOptions){
   elem.Click(); //or elem.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
}
```

See [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232544/selenium-webdriver-and-dropdown-boxes) that has already been answered.