# How can I quickly select an option from a dropdown using Haskell and webdriver?

Tags: selenium, haskell, webdriver

I have a site with a `<select>` that has more than 100 `<option>`s in it, one for every country in the world. My test needs to select one. My current solution - below - takes around 2.5 seconds. I'd like it to be much faster.

```
findChildrenByLabel :: (WD.WebDriver m, MonadIO m) =>
  Text -> Text -> m [WD.Element]
findChildrenByLabel label tagName = do
  parentEl <- findFieldByLabel label
  WD.findElemsFrom parentEl $ WD.ByTag tagName

findChildByLabelF :: (WD.WebDriver m, MonadIO m) =>
  Text -> Text -> (WD.Element -> m Bool) -> m WD.Element
findChildByLabelF label tagName f = do
  children <- findChildrenByLabel label tagName
  child <- filterM f children
  liftIO $ child `shouldSatisfy` ((==1) . length)
  return (headEx child)

selectDropdownByLabel :: (WD.WebDriver m, MonadIO m) => Text -> Text -> m ()
selectDropdownByLabel label optionName = do
  targetOption <- findChildByLabelF
    label "option" (\el -> (== optionName) <$> WD.getText el)
  WD.click targetOption
```

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232544/selenium-webdriver-and-dropdown-boxes) in Java, but there doesn't seem to be anything like `Selenium.Support` or `SelectByText` for Haskell.

Comment: Insted of extracting all the options in `WD.findElemsFrom`, perhaps targeting  a specific option using a dynamically generated XPath expression like `"//option[contains(text(), 'SomeOption')]"` would be faster. It seems that it would save you multiple calls to `WD.getText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on danidiaz's answer, I wrote this:

```
findFieldByLabel :: (WD.WebDriver m, MonadIO m) => Text -> m WD.Element
findFieldByLabel str = do
  labels :: [WD.Element] <- WD.findElems $ WD.ByXPath $
    "//label[text() = \"" <> str <> "\"]"
  els <- catMaybes <$> mapM (`WD.attr` "for") labels
  liftIO $ els `shouldSatisfy` ((==1) . length)
  WD.findElem $ WD.ById $ headEx els

selectDropdownByLabel :: (WD.WebDriver m, MonadIO m) => Text -> Text -> m ()
selectDropdownByLabel label optionName = do
  field <- findFieldByLabel label
  targetOptions <- WD.findElemsFrom field $ WD.ByXPath $
    "option[text() = \"" <> optionName <> "\"]"
  liftIO $ targetOptions `shouldSatisfy` ((==1) . length)
  WD.click $ headEx targetOptions
```

I use it like this:

```
selectDropdownByLabel "Country of residence" "United States"
```

The original solution took around 2.5 seconds, this is around 0.16. Big improvement, thanks danidiaz!