# Click on arrow button in service cloud console using selenium

Tags: selenium, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I need to click on the arrow [Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKGiY.png) in service cloud console to get the different option using selenium with java.

I have been trying to do it by using

```
build.moveToElement(casebutton, -buttonWidth - 2, -1).click().build().perform();
```

But its not working. Please help.

Comment: Can you add html as well for what you required ?

Comment: @NarendraRajput: I have mentioned the button image in my question. Could you please elaborate what is that you need

Comment: add few lines html code related to you button it will help other to identify what exactly there ?

Comment: HTML code for the button,
Here ids changes with each login. So i used class (x-btn-split)
<em class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on" id="ext-gen68"><button type="button" id="ext-gen33" class=" x-btn-text"><div class="mruIcon"></div><span>Cases</span></button></em>

Comment: I think you should find that `down arrow` button element and then do preform simple click

Comment: @NarendraRajput : i have tried the simple click but it not working for this arrow

Comment: You can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7232544/4675568

Comment: Its not actually a standard dropdown list. So can't use it also