# Selenium Xpath for drop down

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Have a doubt.I am new for selenium. I have to access the drop down menus.But not having classname/id for it.
Xpath of that menu is

```
/html/body/div[1]/aside/section/ul/li[3]/a
```

for further drop down is

```
/html/body/div[1]/aside/section/ul/li[4]/a
```

How can i access the drop down menu.by xpath. Surfed alot.

Comment: Can you share the site URL or can add some html code in your questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver and DropDown Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232544/selenium-webdriver-and-dropdown-boxes)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7235199/8204715 will help you.

The main idea is to get a drop-down menu as a WebElement and then work with it as with separate item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you actually want but you can use drop down like this:

```
Select sampleDropDown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("value")));
        sampleDropDown.selectByVisibleText("Values");  //using visible text
        sampleDropDown.selectByIndex(1); //using Index
```

You can get full example [here](https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html)